# PHP simplexml addchild in element with attributes

Tags: php

I am a newbie in php and i don't had my answer on google. So i hope you can help me.

I want to add a child in my xml file with SimpleXML. I think the code is speaking more :

Before

```
<data>
<categorie id="Search">
    <fav>
        <nom>Google</nom>
        <lien>www.google.fr</lien>
    </fav>
    <fav>
        <nom>Orange</nom>
        <lien>www.orange.fr</lien>
    </fav>
</categorie>
<categorie id="Social">
    <fav>
        <nom>Facebook</nom>
        <lien>www.facebook.com</lien>
    </fav>
</categorie>
</data>
```

After

```
<data>
<categorie id="Search">
    <fav>
        <nom>Google</nom>
        <lien>www.google.fr</lien>
    </fav>
    <fav>
        <nom>Orange</nom>
        <lien>www.orange.fr</lien>
    </fav>
</categorie>
<categorie id="Social">
    <fav>
        <nom>Facebook</nom>
        <lien>www.facebook.com</lien>
    </fav>
    <fav>
        <nom>Youtube</nom>
        <lien>www.youtube.com</lien>
    </fav>
</categorie>
</data>
```

So i don't have any idea to add Youtube for example in categorie "Social".

For the moment i get the result of the form in php.

```
$lien = $_POST['link'];
$nom = $_POST['name'];
$categorie = $_POST['cat'];
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Where is your `$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr)` code?

Comment: I read the doc and i think this is : `$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement(../data/data.xml)` and i think the next line is `$fav = $sxe->categorie->addChild('fav');` but not work !

Comment: ok i think i have a begining of the solution. By reading the doc: `$data = new SimpleXMLElement('data.xml');
$fav = $data->categorie[0]->addChild('fav');
$fav = addChild('link', 'toto');
$fav = addChild('desc', 'tutu');

echo $data->asXML();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('../data/data.xml');
$fav = $xml->categorie[0]->addChild("fav"," ");
$fav->addChild("link","toto");
$fav->addChild("desc","tutu");

$xml->asXML('../data/data.xml');
```